# Showing and hiding <option> with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three selects (html drop down lists), all contain the exact same values (except the ids of selects are different).

Now I want to do this:

- When a user selects some option in the first select the same option is hidden in the other two. This rule applies to other two selects as well.
- If the option in the second select is changed again then the previously selected option must reappear in the other selects.

I hope I was clear. I know this should probably be solved with javascript but I don't have enough knowledge of it to write an elegant solution (mine would probably be very long). Can you help me with the this?

Comment: can you post the html structure please

Comment: Can you elaborate on the second item? "If the option in the second select is changed..." I couldn't understand very well what you want.

Comment: IS the `option` text, and/or its `value` the same between all the `select` elements? Also, if multiple choices from the one set are allowed why not use either checkboxes or a multiple-select?

Comment: To make what you want you will most likely need to use `index`. http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: My option text and its value is the same yes. There are too many options for checkboxes (would not be clear) and I didn't even think of multiple-select :D Will try that now, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#selectboxid').hide();
```

is the simplest way

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

try toggle it it matches your requirement

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

you can call these `onchange` of the select box

**if you want to hide individual options**

use `.addClass` and add class to that option to hide it

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: I think the questioner wants to hide individual options, not whole `<select>` elements.

Comment: @frederic did you put any loop for adding "this is a great comment" . even after editing the answer people go on adding :-)

Answer (score 1):

Little late the party, but here's a full working solution:
HTML:

```
<select>
    <option value="Fred">Fred</option>
        <option value="Jim">Jim</option>
        <option value="Sally">Sally</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="Fred">Fred</option>
        <option value="Jim">Jim</option>
        <option value="Sally">Sally</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="Fred">Fred</option>
        <option value="Jim">Jim</option>
        <option value="Sally">Sally</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {
       var $this = $(this);
       var selected = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
       var index = $this.index();
        $("select").each(function() {
             var $this2 = $(this);
            if($this2.index() != index) {
            $(this.options).show();
            var $op = $this2.children("option:[value='" + selected + "']");
            $op.hide();
            if($this2.val() == selected) {
                 if($op.index() + 1 == $ops.length) {
                    $this2.val($ops.eq(0).val());
                }
                else {
                    $this2.val($ops.eq($op.index() + 1).val());
                }
            }
        }
        });
   });
});
```

Also demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/thomas4g/u2sbd/21/